# Show another form over main form in separate thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am trying to show another form over main form in separate thread on button click using background worker thread using following code:

```
    private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //this.Opacity = 50.5;
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();                      
        GetData();
        bw.CancelAsync();

    }

    private void GetData()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++)
        {
            datatable.Rows.Add(new object[] { "raj", "raj", "raj", i });
        }
    }

    void bw_DoWork(object sender,DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        XtraForm1 frm = new XtraForm1();
        while (!bw.CancellationPending)
        {
            frm.ShowDialog();
            frm.BringToFront();
            continue;
        }
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

But the problem is that when I click on the main form, another form running in separate thread gets hide. How can I make it visible until main thread completes its execution and then dispose it nicely?

Comment: Why you want to create UI element in thread rather than UI thread?

Comment: Use a Modal dialog.. not this.. :/

Comment: I want to show something like splash screen showing waiting.. text when main thread is busy in execution

Comment: @SimonWhitehead how can i use modal dialog here ..

Comment: Have the Modal dialog spawn a thread. That thread can notify the UI that things are happening while it is doing its work. (This is essentially what the answers below are saying)

Comment: @SimonWhitehead you mean to say i need to run the splash screen form in main thread and do the other processing  in secondory thread ?

Comment: @RajeevKumar That's indeed the way to go when doing long operations.

Answer (score 3):

The simply answer is: you don't. The UI has a single thread to do all visible user interaction and it should be the UIs job to show a nice "Working..." window to your user before giving control to your worker. Once the worker is done, the window can be closed.

Your "main" (the UI) thread should never be "busy". That will freeze your window. Load off all work to your background task and have the main thread idle around waiting for your worker to complete. Your worker thread can be busy in an endless loop, your UI will still be responsive. Even if the response is only "still working, sorry".

Answer (score 2):

You should do it the other way around. Move your loop to the `BackgroundWorker` and the keep UI stuff (showing your secondary form) in the main thread. Then use `BackgroundWorker`'s `ReportProgress` and `RunWorkerCompleted` etc. to properly show/hide your secondary form.

It would look something like this:
    XtraForm1 frm = new XtraForm1();

```
private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bw.ReportsProgress = true;
    bw.RunWorkerAsync();                      
    frm.ShowDialog();
}

private void GetData()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++)
    {
        datatable.Rows.Add(new object[] { "raj", "raj", "raj", i });
        if(i%1000==0) bw.ReportProgress((int)((i/500000f)*100));
    }
}

void bw_DoWork(object sender,DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    GetData();
}

void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //update your secondary form's UI here. I'm supposing you have a ProgressBar
    //on your form named 'pbr' (make that control public)
    frm.pbr.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}    

void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    frm.Hide();
}
```

Comment: I can't do this as i have no of operation in main thread. so can't do every thing in background worker thread

Comment: @RajeevKumar You can. Your background thread can report progress to the UI thread whilst it is busy doing work.